# Set <fmt:message> tag inside placeholder

Tags: java, html, jsp, properties

I have  This html code:

```
<td  style="padding:1%; " width="80%"><form:textarea  name="reference"  path="" placeholder="insert_word"  width="100%" /></td>
```

I want to get the placeholder word from language.properties file,
I have file langueage.properties:

```
insert_word=add your word here!
```

How can I do that with using `<fmt:message>` tag; 
I already add this lines at the begin of my html code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

<fmt:setBundle basename="language"  />
```

When I put the `<fmt:message>`tag inside the "value", it's working fine,
but inside the placeholder I get some error:

```
<td  style="padding:1%; " width="80%"><form:textarea  name="reference"  path="" placeholder=<fmt:message key="insert_word" />  width="100%" /></td>
```

The error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/ContactForm.jsp (line: 188, column: 98) quote symbol expected
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:89)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttribute(Parser.java:224)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:162)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:153)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1229)
                              .........
```

If I add some qoute (" "/' ') I get this line inside:

```
"<fmt:message key="insert_word" />"
```

Not the translation of insert_word.

What can't I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may not use a JSP tag inside an attribute of another JSP tag.

But you can use variables:

```
<%-- translate the message key and store it in a variable --%>
<fmt:message key="insert_word" var="insertTranslation" />

<%-- use it as placeholder of textarea --%>
<form:textarea  name="reference"  path="" placeholder="${insertTranslation}" width="100%" />
```